# Meaning of Canvas arc function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am working with canvas arc  function.I am unable to figure out the meaning of last two parameters.
Please help me with the meaning of parameters.Thank You

```
ctx.arc(x, y, 70,0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

Comment: You can look at MDN for more information about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the end angle, previous parameters say that the arc starts at 0 angle to 2PI.

2PI = 360° so you are drawing a circle.